# creating a function to return a dictionary with the keys as given divisors and the values are taken from a range

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I've run into a wall. I'm trying to write a function that will take in three inputs: divisors(list), lower, and upper (where upper>=lower) and return a dictionary whose keys are the elements of divisors and whose values are the list of numbers between lower and upper (including the upper value) that are divisible by the corresponding divisor ( if no number in the range is divisible by a certain divisor, the value of that divisor key in the dictionary should be an empty list (returning key:[]).

These are my attempt:

```
def create_divisor_dict(divisor,lower,upper):
    l=lower
    u=upper+1
    d=divisor 
    dict={}
    r=range(l,u)
    for i in r:
        for j in d:
            if i % j == 0:
                dict[j]= i
            else:
                dict[j]=[]
    return (dict)
```

and returned after testing

```
In: create_divisor_dict([1,2,5],2,4)
Out: {1: 4, 2: 4, 5: []}
```

and should return

```
Out: {1:[2,3,4],2:[2,4],5:[]}
```

I've also tried:

```
def create_divisor_dict(divisor,lower,upper):
    l=lower
    u=upper+1
    r=range(l,u)
    d=divisor
    dict={}
    for a in r:
        for b in d:
            if a % b == 0:
                dict[b].append(a)
            else:
                dict[b]=[]
    return (dict)
```

and got a `KeyError: 1`

And tried:

```
def create_divisor_dict(divisor,lower,upper):
    l=lower
    u=upper+1
    r=range(l,u)
    DicDivisor=dict.fromkeys(divisor)
    for a in r:
        for key in DicDivisor:
            if a % key == 0:
                DicDivisor[key].append(a)
            else:
                DicDivisor[key]=[]
    return (DicDivisor)
```

getting `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'`

Thanks for any help that is given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know beforehand that you always want (at least) an empty list in the result, it makes your life much easier to build the complete dictionary with empty lists first and fill it afterwards.

```py
def create_divisor_dict(divisor, lower, upper):
    result = {d:[] for d in divisor}
    
    for d in divisor:
        for i in range(lower, upper+1):
            if i % d == 0:
                result[d].append(i)
    
    return result

>>> create_divisor_dict([1,2,5], 2, 4)
{1: [2, 3, 4], 2: [2, 4], 5: []}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply and advice!

Answer (score 0):

Here try this. Bud a dictionary with empty lists as values and add values as you iterate

```
def create_divisor_dict(divisor,lower,upper):
    l=lower
    u=upper+1
    d=divisor 
    r=range(l,u)
    dict1={j:[] for j in d}
    for i in r:
        for j in d:
            if i % j ==0:
                dict1[j].append(i)
               
    return (dict1)
print(create_divisor_dict([1,2,5],2,4))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create an empty list for each divisor then loop through the range and if a value is divisible by the divisor append it to the list.

```py
def create_divisor_dict(divisor,lower,upper):
    result = {}
    for div in divisor:
        lst = []
        for num in range(lower, upper+1):
            if num % div == 0:
                lst.append(num)
        result[div] = lst
    return result
```

```
Sample Output
>>> create_divisor_dict([1,2,5],2,4)
{1: [2, 3, 4], 2: [2, 4], 5: []}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can invert the `for` loops and, to have the default value as empty list, you can use a list comprehension to filter the divisors (when all divisors are filtered out it will default to an empty list):

```
def create_divisors_dict(divisor, lower, upper):

    dict_ = {}
    
    for div in divisors:
        dict_[div] = [i for i in range(lower, upper + 1) if i % div == 0]
           
    return dict_
```

Notice that I changed `dict` to `dict_` to do not shadow the keyword `dict` which is also used to create dictionaries in Python.
Sample output:

```
In [6]: create_divisors_dict([1,2,5],2,4)
Out[6]: {1: [2, 3, 4], 2: [2, 4], 5: []}
```